# how to prevent skype crashing the wifi connection

Tags: wireless, skype

The skype program on my ubuntu 14 causes crash in my wifi.
After one minute in a call my wifi crashes and i have to restart my computer.
I want to fix this issue so that I can speak with Skype without problems.

A small research in the web revealed two suggestions:

- change the port to something different of 80
- disable upnp

I checked that my port is something reasonable and not 80.
Additionally I don't see the upnp option, so i assume it is ok

The command sudo lshw -C network gives

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 54:27:1e:28:9d:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=3.16.0-14-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0700000-d0703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 40:16:7e:3f:63:57
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:106 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d0614000-d0614fff memory:d0610000-d0613fff
```

what can i check more?

Comment: Is UPnP an available option in your router? Is it on or off?

Comment: i disabled upnp on the router and it worked in most cases. I have one person which when i call still causes crashes in my wifi connection. what can i check more?

Comment: What is the wireless driver? sudo lshw -C network

Comment: i updated the thread above with the command output

Comment: To better see what goes wrong when it crashes, we'd like to see the log just after a crash: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e rtl -e etwork | tail -n20 As the output is 20 lines long, please paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Thanks.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8301758/

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly are you asking? Do you want to know how to fix this problem or what to check to see what's causing the problem?

Comment: I am asking how to fix the problem.I want to use Skype without problems

Comment: Can you edit your post to reflect that, then?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your wireless crashing but simply disconnecting. Is that what you are seeing?

It appears that your access point or router is set to use WPA2-TKIP. I think you will have better luck with WPA2-AES. I suggest you change the encryption method in the router.

I also see a lot of this:

```
rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_phy_switch_wirelessband():<0-0> 5G  
rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_phy_switch_wirelessband():<0-0> 2.4G  
rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_phy_switch_wirelessband():<0-0> 5G  
rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_phy_switch_wirelessband():<0-0> 2.4G
```

In other words, the device is trying to see the access point on the 2.4 GHz band and then hopping to 5 GHz and then back. You might try disabling the 5 GHz band experimentally to see if it helps.

Finally, I suggest you try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8812ae
sudo modprobe rtl8812ae swenc=1
```

If it helps, we can write one file to make it persistent.

Comment: the change from WPA2-TKIP to WPA2-AES did not help. I could not find any place where to disable the 5GHz band.